# Making custom view bigger in the y

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view and I'm trying to dynamically make it bigger in the Y direction. That is the only direction that doesn't work. If I adjust any of the other variables in my custom view the rectangle gets affected in the appropriate ways. If I try adding to `bottomY` then the bottom border disappears and nothing draws below that. Here is the code for the view:

```
private class RectView extends View{

    float leftX, rightX, topY, bottomY;
    boolean isAppt;
    boolean isBeforeTime;
    boolean isSelected;
    public Paint rectPaint;
    private RectF rectangle;
    String time;

    public RectView(Context context, float _leftX, float _rightX, float _topY, float _bottomY,
            boolean _isAppt, boolean _isBeforeTime, String _time){
        super(context);
        leftX = _leftX;
        rightX = _rightX;
        topY = _topY;
        bottomY = _bottomY;
        isAppt = _isAppt;
        isBeforeTime = _isBeforeTime;
        time = _time;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){

        rectPaint = new Paint();

        if(leftX > rightX || topY > bottomY)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MyUtility.LogD_Common("Left = " + leftX + ", Top = " + topY + ", Right = " + rightX +
                ", Bottom = " + bottomY);
        rectangle = new RectF(leftX, topY, rightX, bottomY);

        float height = bottomY;
        float width = rightX - leftX;
        MyUtility.LogD_Common("Height = " + height + ", Width = " + width);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, (int) height);
        //params.leftMargin = (int) leftX;
        params.bottomMargin = 10;
        //params.rightMargin = 10;
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        MyUtility.LogD_Common("Right = " + rightX);
        rectangle.left = leftX;
        rectangle.right = rightX;
        rectangle.top = topY;
        rectangle.bottom = bottomY;
        if(!isSelected){
            if(isAppt){
                if(isBeforeTime)
                    rectPaint.setARGB(144, 119, 98, 95);
                else
                    rectPaint.setARGB(144, 217, 131, 121);
                //119,98,95
                rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            }
            else{
                rectPaint.setARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
                rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            }
            canvas.drawRect(rectangle, rectPaint);
            if(isAppt){
                rectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                rectPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
                rectPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
                canvas.drawRect(rectangle, rectPaint);
            }
        }
        else{

            rectPaint.setARGB(144, 197, 227, 191);
            rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawRect(rectangle, rectPaint);
            rectPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            rectPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            rectPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawRect(rectangle, rectPaint);              

        }
    }

}
```

Why is this happening and why only in the positive Y direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create this object you call `init()`, where you set the height spec for your RelativeLayout params to the local variable `height`, which you define with:

```
float height = bottomY;
```

By doing this, you are telling the parent RelativeLayout that this view want's to be exactly that height that `bottomY` was when you created the object.

If you then increase the value of `bottomY` for your already created object, it can no longer fit inside the height you defined in your RelativeLayout params when the object was first created.

Firstly, Changing the LayoutParams from inside the class in this way is not recommended. This makes your custom View inflexible. If you set a bunch of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams inside the class, then your custom View can only ever be used in a RelativeLayout.
You should instead set the LayoutParams in your code before you add the view. For example:

```
RectView rectView = new RectView(...);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
addView(rectView, params);
```

Secondly, when the system draws the layout that your custom view has been added to, it goes through a series of steps. In the layout process it will call `getMeasuredWidth()` and  `getMeasuredHeight()` on all it's child views (including your custom view). You should override your custom views `onMeasure()` method and get it to report the correct size of your view. Have a look at `onMeasure()` in the example in the reference documentation for [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). It's a more complex `onMeasure()` than you need for your case, but it gives you the basic idea.

In your particular case something like the following should do the trick:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

// This method calculates the Width of your view based on the dimensions of
// your rectangle and the current widthMeasureSpec.
private int measureWidth(int widthMeasureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);        

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Return the width of the rectangle
        result = rightX - leftX;
    }
    return result;
}

// This method calculates the Height of your view based on the dimensions of
// your rectangle and the current widthMeasureSpec.
private int measureHeight(int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Return the height of the rectangle
            result = bottomY - topY;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to get around this then making a new rectview of the appropriate size?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the better approach

Comment: I made a small modification to the code and it works. For anyone interested I changed the line `result = bottomY - topY;` to just `result = bottomY;` because I am using a relative layout and that requires absolute coordinates. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!